# Why is my ForkJoinPool program running so slow?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, parallel-processing, forkjoinpool

I'm learning about parallel programming in Java using fork join pool. I know how it works internally and decided to write a very simple program using it to calculate the max value for a large array. However, when I ran it I found that it would take so long that the program would hang and never complete. When I just calculate the max without using parallelism though it was much faster and finished in milliseconds! Also, when I use Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors() my computer returns 8, so it's not like I'm using a 1 core computer that can't handle it. Can somebody tell me if they are getting similar results on their own computer? If so, can you explain what is wrong with my code, i'm very confused. Thanks.

```
import java.util.concurrent.*;

public class ParralleMax {
  private static int numberOfCores = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
  
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] list = new int[9_000_000];
    for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++)
      list[i] = i;
    System.out.println("Array created. Program now starting...");
    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    int max = calculateMax(list);
    long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println("This computer has " + numberOfCores + " cores.");
    System.out.println("The max value " + max + " was calculated in " + (endTime - startTime) + " 
    miliseconds.");     
  }

  public static int calculateMax(int[] list) {
    RecursiveTask<Integer> maxTask = new MaxTask(list, 0, list.length);
    ForkJoinPool pool = new ForkJoinPool();
    return pool.invoke(maxTask);
  }

  private static class MaxTask extends RecursiveTask<Integer> {
    private final static int THRESHOLD = 1000;
    private int[] list;
    private int low;
    private int high;

    public MaxTask(int[] list, int low, int high) {
      this.list = list;
      this.low = low;
      this.high = high;
    }
    @Override
    public Integer compute() {
      if (high - low < THRESHOLD) {
        int max = list[0];
        for (int i = low; i < high; i++) 
          if (list[i] > max)
            max = list[i];
        return new Integer(max);
      }
      else {
        int mid = (high + low) / 2;
        RecursiveTask left = new MaxTask(list, 0, mid);
        RecursiveTask right = new MaxTask(list, mid, high);
    
        right.fork();
        left.fork();
        Integer leftMax = (Integer)left.join();
        Integer rightMax = (Integer)right.join();
        return new Integer(Math.max(leftMax.intValue(), rightMax.intValue()));
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Isn't there a typo in the line `RecursiveTask left = new MaxTask(list, 0, mid);`. Should it be `RecursiveTask left = new MaxTask(list, low, mid);` instead?

Comment: @caco3 literally fixed it... I'm so dumb. Thanks so much!